# Numpy seems to be producing different results when a matrix is raised to nth power using different methods

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvector

For a 2x2 matrix A, let T be the matrix containing it's eigenvectors.
Let D be a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of A on it's diagonal.

Therefore, AT = TD

Assuming T is invertible, A = TDT<sup>-1</sup>

Notice that A<sup>n</sup> = TD<sup>n</sup>T<sup>-1</sup>

The above equation implies that e<sup>(TDT<sup>-1</sup>)</sup> = Te<sup>(D)</sup>T<sup>-1</sup> because of power series expansion of the exponent function.

But when I tried this using numpy, it is producing different results for e<sup>(TDT<sup>-1</sup>)</sup> and Te<sup>(D)</sup>T<sup>-1</sup>

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA

A = np.array([[3, -1],[-1, 3]])
e_values, e_vectors = LA.eig(A)
D = np.diag(e_values)
T = e_vectors.T

r1 = np.matmul(T, np.matmul(np.exp(D), LA.inv(T)))
r2 = np.exp(np.matmul(T, np.matmul(D, LA.inv(T))))

print("r1: ", r1,"\nr2: ", r2)
```

The above outputs

```
r1:  [[29.99360307 23.60454697]
 [23.60454697 31.99360307]] 
r2:  [[20.08553692  2.71828183]
 [ 2.71828183 20.08553692]]
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a pathological case.  If you `print(np.matmul( T, D, LA.inv(T)))`, you'll find that the result is NOT "A", as you'd expect.

Comment: Are you sure your first statement is correct?  I just ran the first four lines of your code, and then looked at `A@T` and `T@D` (the new way of writing matrix multiply).  The results were not the same.  Also, it's unclear why your exponential equation is true.  This is not "matrix exponentiation", but exponentiation of each of the individual elements.

Comment: As @FrankYellin pointed out, `np.exp` does element-wise exponentation; it does not compute the matrix exponential.  For the matrix exponential, you could use `scipy.linalg.expm`.  Also, don't transpose `e_vectors` to get `T`; the columns of `e_vectors` are the eigenvectors, which is what you want for `T`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Using scipy finally did the job. Thank you for your response!